# I want an output that looks like: "Paste R2 has the most files with 32 files." using a function

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

Question 1: I want an output that looks like: "Paste R2 has the most files with 32 files."

I created a function but only got the maximum value and I also want the corresponding paste

```
data = [['R1', 28], ['R2', 32], ['R3', 1], ['L4', 0],
        ['L5', 10], ['L6', 22], ['L7', 30], ['L8', 19]]
```

where e.g. `R1` is a paste and 28 is the number of files on that paste

```
def max_past(a_list):
    list_of_index1 = [i[1] for i in a_list]
    return max(list_of_index1)

print(f"Paste {data[0]}has the most files with {max_past(data)} files")
```

Question 2: How can I use a function that will give me the number of files of the paste with an `R` in its name (R1, R2, R3)??

Comment: Question 1) your "question 1" does not have a question. Question 2) could you please clarify? Your `data` already provides the number of files along with the corresponding `R`s.

Comment: My question 1 is how can i get that output since i am being successfull in return the maximum number of files but a also want in which paste they are.

Comment: Regarding 2nd question, I want a function for which the input is a letter (either "R",or "L" ) and the function returns the total number of files counted at all pastes that start with that letter. And then, find in which type of pastes (R or L) there are more files.

Comment: Have you tried to solve the second question yourself? If you have, please include your attempt in the post

Comment: I got "IndexError: string index out of range"

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't help identify the issue at all. Please post the _code_ that causes this exception

Comment: def max_files(a_list):
    list_of_index1 = [i[1] for i in a_list]
    return max(list_of_index1)

what I did: print(f"Paste {data[i][0]}has the most files with {max_files(data)}")
output: i is not defined 

what i want: R1 is a paste and 28 is the number of files on that paste

Comment: This should instead raise a `NameError` because in `data[i][0]` the name `i` is undefined. Anyway, why are you not using the code provided in any of the answers? Your code doesn't work because the function only returns the number of birds (or flies, or files), but not the name of the bird (the `R1, R2, R3...`). To retrieve the name this number corresponds to, you'll need to search for it, traversing the list `data` _for the second time_, like `next(name for name, number in data if number == the_number_returned_by_max_birds)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the maximum using [the `key` parameter of the `max` function](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#max):

```
>>> max(data, key=lambda element: element[1])
['R2', 32]
>>> print(f"Paste {_[0]}has the most files with {_[1]} files")
Paste R2has the most files with 32 files
```

Comment: def max_past(a_list):
    list_of_index1 = [i[1] for i in a_list]
    return max(list_of_index1)

print(f"Paste {data[0]}has the most files with {max_past(data)} files")

My problem is in "{data[0]}" because i am sure that it is wrong. I already get the maximum number os files with that function but also want the paste in which that number is

Comment: You don't need to write your own function. The built-in `max` can already do this, as shown in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
"""Question 1"""
data = [['R1', 28], ['R2', 32], ['R3', 1], ['L4', 0],
    ['L5', 10], ['L6', 22], ['L7', 30], ['L8', 19]]

data.sort(key= lambda val: val[1], reverse = True)

print(f"Paste {data[0][0]} has the most files with {data[0][1]} files")
#Paste R2 has the most files with 32 files

"""Question 2"""
new_list = []
for elem in data:
   if 'R' in elem[0]:
       new_list.append(elem)


#[['R2', 32], ['R1', 28], ['R3', 1]]
```

Change R to whatever you want. Create a function from this snippet.